# PyQt5 font size changing between desktop and surface pro

Tags: python-3.x, fonts, pyqt, surface

I wrote a GUI for my desktop a while ago and have just tried to run it on a surface pro 3 only to find the fonts are all exceeding their bounding boxes. Labels are exceeding the worst. Disabling the bold attribute helps when it comes to buttons but not by much.

I have checked to make sure the chosen fonts are compatible for both devices.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and know of a fix for it?

Thanks,

Comment: On which platform you developed the application (the desktop one you mentioned)?

Comment: Hi Daniele, Windows 8 and 10

Comment: That's odd. I faced a similar problem when distributing a Qt app created on Mac OS: on Windows fonts were bigger and were exceeding all the boundaries. This doesn't seem to be your problem though.

Comment: Interesting, what was your solution?

Comment: I subclassed the `QFont` class and in the constructor I multiplied the point size by a factor of 0.75 whenever the current platform match 'win32' (by checking sys.platform)